# Which AtomicInteger methods are test-and-set, fetch-and-add and compare-and-swap (in terms of lock-free algorithms)?

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic, lock-free, atomicinteger

CAS (*compare-and-swap*) : `boolean compareAndSet(int expect, int update)`

FAA(*fetch-and-add*) : `int addAndGet(int delta)` ???

TAS (*test-and-set*) : ???

In my understanding:

CAS (*compare-and-swap*) "synchronizes" (w/o locks, on CPU instructions level) code like this:

```
if(a==b) {
  a++;  // or a = a + 7;
}
```

FAA (*fetch-and-add*) : "synchronizes" (w/o locks, on CPU instructions level) code like this:

```
x = x + 7;
```

But I am not sure about what kind of code "test-and-set" related to.

Answer (score 2):

Test-and-set is an atomic RMW operation that sets the value at a memory location to `1` and returns the old value (either `1` or `0`).

There is no "true" test-and-set operation in Java but you can simulate it by passing `1` to `AtomicInteger::getAndSet` and expecting it to return `1` or `0`. Alternatively, you can simulate TAS by passing `true` to `AtomicBoolean::getAndSet` and expecting `true` or `false`.

It's not so useful in the example you provided where you increment a variable since TAS is a binary operation.